Why is the read-only RegexGenerator.g.cs file (autogenerated by GeneratedRegex attribute) throwing CS0165
In my project, I use the GeneratedRegex attribute like so:
public partial class Game
{
    ...

    [GeneratedRegex(@"<regex>", RegexOptions.Compiled, "en-US")]
    private static partial Regex MoveLegalityRegex();

    ...
}

The regex inputted into the generator is:
@"(?<!.)(([1-4](10|a|A|k|K|q|Q|j|J|[2-9]))|bs)(?(?<=bs)| ??: ??(?(?<=1\3 ??: ??)(10|a|A|k|K|q|Q|j|J|[2-9]){1}|((?<=2.{2,5}?)(10|a|A|k|K|q|Q|j|J|[2-9]){2}|((?<=3.{2,5}?)(10|a|A|k|K|q|Q|j|J|[2-9]){3}|((?<=4.{2,5}?)(10|a|A|k|K|q|Q|j|J|[2-9]){4})))))(?!.)"
When I compile my code to run, it throws the following error: Line 466: Use of unassigned local variable 'lazyloop_iteration' (CS0165)
After some digging in the RegexGenerator.g.cs file, I find the relevant chunk of code:
// Match ' ' lazily, optionally.
//{
    pos++;
    slice = inputSpan.Slice(pos);
    int lazyloop_iteration = 0;
    lazyloop_pos = pos;
    goto LazyLoopEnd;
    
    LazyLoopBacktrack:
    UncaptureUntil(lazyloop_capturepos);
    if (lazyloop_iteration >= 1)
    {
        goto CaptureBacktrack2;
    }
    lazyloop_iteration++;
    if (Utilities.s_hasTimeout)
    {
        base.CheckTimeout();
    }
    
    pos = lazyloop_pos;
    slice = inputSpan.Slice(pos);
    if (slice.IsEmpty || slice[0] != ' ')
    {
        goto CaptureBacktrack2;
    }
    pos++;
    slice = inputSpan.Slice(pos);
    lazyloop_pos = pos;
    
    LazyLoopEnd:
    lazyloop_capturepos = base.Crawlpos();
//}

I can't edit this file, as it is auto-generated so I'm not sure what to do.
Can anyone explain how I can fix this, if there is a problem with my regex, or is there some other issue going on?
I tried using the GeneratedRegex attribute with the regex described.
I expected the GeneratedRegex would generate an implementation of my specified regex without issue or error.
The resulting regex generated was not error-free and I was not able to fix it, as the file is read-only.
UPDATE:
When I try to compile the project, it fails because of this error.
I'm using .NET version 7. For me, SYSLIB1044 (couldn't generate implementation) does not appear on my code and there is a file generated by the RegexGenerator that includes a full source implementation of the regex. It does not include any remarks about it being unable to support any feature of my regex.
Restarting Visual Studio does not fix the issue. Neither does running the project directly from the terminal using dotnet run.

not answering your question directly, but this sounds like a warning, not an error. Maybe you have warnings treated as error in your project configuration? You could maybe isolate this code part in another library project and disable the warning treated as error there, so you can keep your strict checks in the rest of the solution? In any case, I would recommend signaling this as a bug on the reference site.

Which .NET version are you using? I just tried your RegEx here and I got the error that The regex generator couldn't generate a complete source implementation for the specified regular expression due to an internal limitation. .

I have a side question related to my above comment, how to open an issue on theis part concerning dotnet? would it be the compiler Roslyn here https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues or or another one?

looking at this again, CS0165 is indeed an error in C#, not a warning, but the error is not consistent with the code. The variable is properly initialized when it is declared. Could you try a clean and rebuild / restart Visual Studio?

Please don't add solutions inside the question. Consider creating an answer, but keep in mind link-only answers are not good answers

@DarkBee Sorry, didn't know!

Fixed by dotnet runtime:
See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/103942
for more details
